# Sound/brightness slider gone in Manjaro Gnome

Tags: gnome, gui, manjaro

since quite some time I have this problem that the background colors of the sound and brightness sliders are gone. I think it's since an update in the past, but I'm not sure anymore.

I couldn't find anything on the web and it would be great to have an idea where I should start looking.

Here is how it looks like:

[image: M]
[image: other control]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve it myself by [resetting my gnome conf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults/959976).

Now it's back, but I also realized setting up my gnome desktop again, that the option "User themes" in the tab extensions of the Gnome tweak tool did remove the sliders again.

So if I want **visible** sliders, I need to **activate** the "User themes" option.